# JavaScript to toggle icons on Accordion when they expand and collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, razor, font-awesome

I have an accordion which expands and collapses. Here is the code:https://jsfiddle.net/96jqo3ba/2/ . I would like to use FontAwesome icon classes  to represent when an accordion tab expands and collapses. 
Here are the two fontAwesome classes that I want to use:

```
<i class="fas fa-plus" /i>
<i class="fas fa-minus" /i>
```

In the cshtml, I have added the `<i class="fas fa-plus"/i>`. My question is, in my Jquery script, how do I toggle between `<i class="fas fa-plus" /i>` and `<i class="fas fa-plus" /i>` when an accordion tab expands and collapses ?

Jquery:

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-toggle");
for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function(evnt) {
    const currClassList = evnt.currentTarget.classList;
    if (currClassList.contains('collapsed')) {
        evnt.currentTarget.classList.remove("collapsed");
        var content = evnt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      for (var j = 0; j < coll.length; j++) {
           coll[j].classList.remove("collapsed")
           coll[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
      }
      this.classList.toggle("collapsed");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.maxHeight){
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same approach as you are using to change the "collapse" class. You just need to get the icon element and add or remove the class as necessary.

Something like this:

```
// Toggle icon
var iconElem = evnt.currentTarget.children[0];
iconElem.classList.remove("fa-minus");
iconElem.classList.add("fa-plus");
```

Which means that your new JS would be:

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-toggle");
for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function(evnt) {
    const currClassList = evnt.currentTarget.classList;
    if (currClassList.contains('collapsed')) {
        evnt.currentTarget.classList.remove("collapsed");
        var content = evnt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        content.style.maxHeight = null;

        // Toggle icon
        var iconElem = evnt.currentTarget.children[0];
        iconElem.classList.remove("fa-minus");
        iconElem.classList.add("fa-plus");
    } else {
      for (var j = 0; j < coll.length; j++) {
           coll[j].classList.remove("collapsed")
           coll[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
           coll[j].children[0].classList.remove("fa-minus");
           coll[j].children[0].classList.add("fa-plus");
      }
      this.classList.toggle("collapsed");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.maxHeight){
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
      // Toggle icon
      var iconElem = evnt.currentTarget.children[0];
      iconElem.classList.remove("fa-plus");
      iconElem.classList.add("fa-minus");
    }
  });
}
```

Here is a working Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/o6j49dcy/

Comment: Hi @Bruno, I viewed your Fiddle and noticed that when collapsing an accordion tab, the icons don't toggle correctly. For example, If I expand accordion 1, and then I expand accordion 2, accordion 1 get collapsed but the icon remains as minus.

Comment: Oops, my bad @Cliff. I updated the code in the answer and the Fiddle. I missed the code inside the loop, which handles this specific case you mentioned. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thank you @Bruno. I have good understanding of your approach on this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your current setup, you could add both the `fa-plus` and `fa-minus` elements in the markup next to each other and then the following css to hide / show them based on if the `collapsed` class is present:

HTML:

```
<h2 class="accordion-toggle"><i class="fa fa-plus pull-right"></i><i class="fa fa-minus pull-right"></i><button>
Open Collapsible
</button></h2>
<div id="anyId" class="collapse">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<h2 class="accordion-toggle"><i class="fa fa-plus pull-right"></i><i class="fa fa-minus pull-right"></i><button>
Open Section 1
</button></h2>
<div class="collapse">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.accordion-toggle {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.collapsed, .accordion-toggle:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapse {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.fa-minus {
  display: none;
}

.collapsed .fa-minus {
  display: block;
}

.collapsed .fa-plus {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Even though this solution would work, having extra and unnecessary elements in the code; is a bad practice. You don't really need 2 icon elements there.

Comment: Sure -- but this is a working solution based on their current set up. It allows the CSS to control the logic of the iconography based on their existing functionality.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I don't see how this would be based on their current set up.

First, the current setup is using Javascript to add or remove CSS classes and your solution is using CSS to show or hide elements. Second, the current setup has only one icon element and your solution is adding an extra icon.

Again, this is a possible/working solution, but a solution that changes the HTML structure and uses a bad practice.
Just a feedback :)